# Better to use Validating or Leave event to validate textbox data?

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

When coding validation logic for a VB .NET textbox, which event handler is better to use: **Validating** or **Leave**?

From what I understand, they both occur at the same time.  However, according to this article: [MSDN: Control.Leave Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx), the Leave event occurs right before the validating event.  This would initially make me think I would rather use the Leave event, as it occurs first.

However, for code readability, it would make sense to place all validation code in the Validating event.

So, which is the better option, in terms of both efficiency and industry-standards?

Comment: If it possible to save the data without leaving the textbox, then your validation code would not be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should **always** use the Validating event, it was made to support validation.  If not to prevent the focus change then at least for the CausesValidation property.  Which you set to False on, say, the Cancel button of a dialog.  No point in validating anything when the user decides to dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The `Validating` event is designed for validation. If the text isn't valid, set e.Cancel = True, and focus stays on the text box. `Leave` is just a notification.