# Detect if textbox value is beeing edited or is edited

Tags: vb.net, textbox, textchanged

I'm currently working on an application that works with 3D CAD software, one feature of my application is easy editing of positioning values.

The problem I encounter now: if the user edits the position value in the control (`Textbox`) the position is instantly updated. Even if the user is still editing the value.

For example when the user edits 1000 to 0 the position will change accordingly if he/she uses backspace.

1. 1000 start position
2. 100
3. 10
4. 1
5. empty value = 0 ( written in my application )
6. 0

How can I detect if the edit of the user is finished?

Comment: Handle the `Validating` event.

Comment: I looked at the msdn info page [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info. Am I correct to assume that the value can anly be validated when focus is lost on the object? either by keyboard or mouse action?

Comment: Yes, Validating gets raised when the user attempts to move focus to another control. There is otherwise no good way to know that they are "finished" entering input, which is exactly the problem you're having with `TextChanged`. You could possibly write code that forces them to press Enter to "commit" their change, but don't, because that's not how Windows applications generally work, so users will not expect yours to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

It has hard to know when the user is done while their cursor/focus is still in the textbox, as some may be slow/inconsistent typists.

A good way to know that they're done (or at least when to update), would be in the <strike>`TextBox_Leave` event</strike>. A better way, pointed out by **Cody Gray**, is with the `TextBox_Validating` event. This gives more control, and is meant specifically for validating.

Please ignore my previous solution.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    'Insert code that updates values here.
End Sub
```

I have been (incorrectly) using the Leave event.

Comment: No, don't use Leave. Use Validating.

Comment: Why use Validating over Leave? Validating will be called when they go to close the program, whereas Leave will not. What are the advantages (I'm unfamiliar)

Comment: I've found this, which is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406528/better-to-use-validating-or-leave-event-to-validate-textbox-data
Which means validating can be used to keep focus on the textbox. I will update my answer

Comment: No, that is precisely when Validating would *not* be raised. Validating is raised under very similar circumstances as Leave. In particular, it is raised whenever the user attempts to set focus to another control. However, it is *not* raised when the user tries to close the window or quit the program because it makes no sense to validate input under those circumstances. Validating should always be preferred because it was explicitly designed to support validation, fixing bugs and bad behavior that will inevitably crop up if you try to handle Leave and implement Validating yourself.

Comment: I understand. I agree, but I would like to point out that Validating is most certainly called when the user tries to close the program (I just tried it myself). However, I think the key is that you can use `e.cancel` to prevent validation.

Comment: Well, the trick is to set the CausesValidation property to false on the control that is used to close the program.

Comment: @CodyGray Exactly. I appreciate your help. I'll be sure to use Validating from now on.